# Что делать если на attiny85 нехватает пинов?

Tags: c++, avr

На днях занимался проектом на attiny85 и столкнулся с проблемой. Подключал OLED экран ssd1306
и мне нужен вход на прерывание pb2(седьмая нога), но вся проблема в том что эта нога используется для связи с экраном(scl). Можно как то программно задать эту ногу на другую или как еще можно сделать?(P.S. места под библиотеки мало )